# How do I use adb grant or adb revoke?

Tags: android, adb, android-permissions

The Android documentation contains the following description of the adb grant and adb revoke commands.

```
grant <PACKAGE_PERMISSION>
```

Grant permissions to applications. Only optional permissions the application has declared can be granted.

```
revoke <PACKAGE_PERMISSION>
```

Revoke permissions to applications. Only optional permissions the application has declared can be revoked.

**Can anybody please give an example of the correct syntax to use them?**

I assume that  would be a permission like `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, or perhaps just `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.  Well I tried those, and several others and I cannot get it to work.

I also tried (to no avail) several combinations of package and permission, which makes more sense to me (this sounds like a command that would modify a permission on one package, not all)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

To Add:

```
adb shell pm grant com.name.app android.permission.READ_PROFILE
```

To Remove:

```
adb shell pm revoke com.name.app android.permission.READ_PROFILE
```

This changed at the release of Android M, so in Lollipop (at original time of writing answer) you needed to do `adb shell` first.

```
adb shell 
pm grant com.name.app android.permission.READ_PROFILE
```

---

A full list of permissions can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html). If you have [android build tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272872/unable-to-run-aapt-command-keeps-returning-android-sdk-build-tools) set up you can see what permissions the app is using. First use

```
adb shell pm list packages -f
```

Then copy the package to you computer:

```
adb pull /path/to/package/from/previous/step.apk
```

Then get permissions:

```
aapt d permissions path/to/app/on/computer.apk
```

Comment: How come PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS cannot be granted this way? Is there an alternative?

Comment: how to use this at runtime ?

Comment: Does this work with platform-signed permissions?

Answer (score 7):

If you happen to not know the name of permission or want to clear all permissions you can use

```
adb shell pm reset-permissions
```

**WARNING**: This will reset run-time permissions for all the apps on your phone. You cannot reset for a specific package.

Comment: **Be careful with this command since it reset all your system permissions.** pm reset-permissions is parameterless. It doesn't care about your.package.name.

Comment: what does reset mean in this context? revoke all permissions? Or set them to whatever the manifest of the app wants?

Answer (score 5):

So here's a little command line (mac/linux) to grant your app all of the permissions it requires from the command line.

```
aapt d permissions ./path/to/your.apk \
  | sed -n \
    -e "s/'//g" \
    -e "/^uses-permission: name=android.permission\./s/^[^=]*=//p" \
  | xargs -n 1 adb shell pm grant com.your.package
```

Comment: Note: After pasting in the command I discovered I needed to remove the first of the '\' characters (immediately after the apk file name) in order for the sed command to run correctly.