# Unable to run aapt command - keeps returning "Android SDK Build-tools"

Tags: android

**What I'm attempting to do:** Install the Android build tools on Mac OSX so I can use the `aapt` command to crunch/process some images for testing

**What I've done:**

1. Installed the Android SDK using brew
2. Run the `android` command to bring up the SDK Manager
3. Used the Manager to install the SDK tools (22.3), SDK Platform-tools(19), SDK Build-tools(19) and Android 4.4
4. I've verified that the tools were added to the default location when using brew.

**What happens:**
Running `aapt` or `aapt v` always returns `Use the 'android' tool to install the "Android SDK Build-tools".`

I've also tried updating the tools using `android update`, but it still fails to work.

**EDIT:**
Running the full path to `aapt v` works. I'm now assuming I have an issue with my `PATH` which I still need to resolve

Any clues as to what to try next would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the Android SDK doesn't try to modify your `PATH` variable for you. If you want to be able to run SDK tools without specifying their full path, you'll need to add the folder(s) containing them to your `PATH` one by one.

You can do this by editing your `~/.bash_profile` and adding a line like so (or editing an existing line like this if you have one already):

```bash
export PATH="$PATH:/PATH/TO/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/17.0.0"
```

Alternatively, you can just specify the full path to the tool when invoking it, like so:

```bash
/PATH/TO/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/17.0.0/aapt v
```

I'm not sure this ever happens with `aapt`, but this can be useful to disambiguate if multiple versions of a tool are installed. To see which version of a command that bash is resolving to, you can usually find out by running `which`, like so:

```bash
which aapt
```

**EDIT**

There have been a number of good comments on this answer including [Jared's excellent suggestion to dynamically add the latest build-tools to the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272872/unable-to-run-aapt-command-keeps-returning-android-sdk-build-tools/20273288#comment68198460_20273288). I reimplemented his code in pure 3.x bash, here's what's currently in my `~/.bash_profile`. First, make sure to set `ANDROID_HOME`:

```bash
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Library/Android/sdk" #Set this to the path to your Android SDK if it's not in the default location
```

Then (if you are using bash):

```bash
BUILD_TOOLS=($ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/*)
ANDROID_LATEST_BUILD_TOOLS="${BUILD_TOOLS[@]:(-1)}"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_LATEST_BUILD_TOOLS"
```

Alternatively, here is a POSIX version that should work in any shell:

```bash
ANDROID_LATEST_BUILD_TOOLS=$(ls -r ${ANDROID_HOME}/build-tools|head -1)
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/$ANDROID_LATEST_BUILD_TOOLS"
```

Comment: I think you're onto something; running `which` showed me another instance of `aapt`. I'm going to try removing it and see if that resolves my issue.

Comment: Excellent: `which aapt` revealed that it was trying to run the command from the wrong location (presumably the tools must have been installed in a different location at some point and then deleted, but the alias remained). Removing the alias and updating the `~/.bash_profile` as described worked.
That's the first time I've encountered `which`; that's a handy command. Thanks!

Comment: I find it helpful to store the build tools version as a separate variable in my profile.  For example... export ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=22.0.1 ...so you can easily point to a different version without changing the PATH and other variables directly... export ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_HOME=$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/build-tools/$ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION ... export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS_HOME:$ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_HOME ... etc.

Comment: Worked perfectly. This saved me so much time.. Thank you!

Comment: You could use the following to get the latest build-tools without modifying each time: `PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/build-tools/$(ls ${ANDROID_HOME}/build-tools | sort -r | head -n 1):${PATH}" `

Comment: @JaredRummler that's awesome, great idea! I updated my answer with my take on dynamic build-tool resolution.