# Is it possible to revoke permission with Espresso?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-espresso

I'm currently writing some tests for an app. If the app does not have storage permission, a fragment pops up. I know how to grant permission with "grant permission rule" but is there a method to revoke permission?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. Quote from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule:

> Once a permission is granted it will apply for all tests running in the current Instrumentation. There is no way of revoking a permission after it was granted. Attempting to do so will crash the Instrumentation process.

What I can suggest is to wrap permission methods into some service and mock the value checking if the permission is granted

Answer (score -1):

Yes, during testing its possible...Feuby gave a somewhat correct answer to the same question in this SO 2017 question

[Android revoke permission at start of each test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462172/android-revoke-permission-at-start-of-each-test)

Repeating his code

public static boolean checkCameraPermission(MainActivity thisActivity) {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) 
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

public static void checkAndAskCameraPermission(final MainActivity thisActivity) {

```
if (!checkCameraPermission(thisActivity)) {
    //No right is granted 
    // Should we show an explanation? 
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) { 

        //Open a dialog explaining why you are asking permission then when when positive button is triggered, call this line 
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        CHECK_FOR_CAMERA_PERMISSION); 

    } else { 
        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission. 
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                CHECK_FOR_CAMERA_PERMISSION); 
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: This is to ask for permission. I want to write a test that takes a permission away so that I can test how my app responds to it.