# Android: how to test permissions with UI Test

Tags: android, android-testing, ui-testing

I've found the code to actually test the permissions. But I don't know how to delete the permissions given (or denied) in order to test every case.

Any idea? Every solution found doesn't work by now (runtime exec, get activity and clear data, etc.)

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462172/android-revoke-permission-at-start-of-each-test

Comment: it almost works. I mean, the first test runs correctly and erases the permissions but the second crashes. Maybe something stay opened, I don't know

Comment: check out this link : https://github.com/ahasbini/AndroidTestMockPermissionUtils

Comment: I think that the premises of that readme are wrong. I mean, I am able to reset the permissions at runtime before the first test start. He states that he wasn't able to do that. My problem is that at the second run I got a "DeadObject" when I invoke the call to reset the permissions and I cannot understand why

Comment: So you claim that `clearPackageData true` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Filnik, the "DeadObject", where is this error coming from or showing in? How are you executing or running your tests? Are you using Roboelectric?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the test orchestrator.

First, you add this to the gradle of the module with the tests that you want the permissions to be cleared for.

```
androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:version'
```

and in the same gradle, you add this to the defaultConfig block in the android block.

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
```

The docs are here if you want more info:
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/androidx-test-libraries/runner